# Why's poignant guide to Ruby chapter 5.7 . The WishScanner module

Tags: ruby

I was reading Why's poignant guide to ruby and came upon this module on chapter 5:

```
require 'endertromb'
module WishScanner

   def scan_for_a_wish

      wish = self.read.detect do |thought|
        thought.index( 'wish: ' ) == 0
      end

      wish.gsub( 'wish: ', '' )
   end
end
```

I have been trying to figure out how it works but what is confusing me is how `thought.index( 'wish: ' ) == 0` and `wish.gsub( 'wish: ', '' )` work. According to the author the purpose of this method is to  *"only pick up a wish if it starts with the word wish and a colon and a space. That way the planet doesn’t fill up with every less-than-ten-letter word that appears in people’s heads.”*

But the way I understand it, `thought.index( 'wish: ' ) == 0` will check if `thought` starts with `'wish: '`. However i dont understand `wish.gsub( 'wish: ', '' )` in the way I see it it seems to just substitute `wish` with an empty string.

Can any one offer any explanation or further insight into it?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `wish.gsub( 'wish: ', '' )` in the way I see it it seems to just substitute wish with an empty string

Exactly! It replaces the string `"wish: "` in a string like `"wish: A pony!"` with `""`.
I.e. it turns "wish: A pony!" into "A pony!".

Comment: I was thinking It would turn the whole wish into an empty string. Then I realized it would only effect the "wish: " string. Thank you for the insight.